# Is Marina an Octoling? If so, how can she be part of Inkling society?

Tags: splatoon-2

[image]

Marina has all the Octoling features in her hair, but if I can remember right, Octoling and Inklings are not supposed to be friendly to each other and have been at war for as long as history can remember.

So is there a reason why Marina is ok being within Inkling society?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Digging around on the web, a lot of sites seem to lead to two things:

- Marina either defected from the Octoling society, or liked the Inkling better, and decided to stay there.  A [GameFAQ post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/200279-splatoon-2/75539415?page=1) discusses this a bit.
- The Sunken Scrolls in Splatoon 2, specifically, the second scroll which depicts the final battle in Hero Mode between Agent 3 and DJ Octavio (explanation below).

The first bullet for the most part speaks for itself, but I think the second bullet is more appropriate and I'll attempt to explain my thoughts.  The in game description for this scroll states:

> Music heads are still buzzing over that legendary underground show two years ago. Anyone lucky enough to catch DJ Octavio's opening set and the Squid Sisters headlining had their minds blown and their lives changed that night.

The scroll can be seen below:

[image: scroll]

Circled in the picture, is Marina, which is also noted on the [Scrolls Wiki page](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Sunken_Scroll) as well as on [Marina's page](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Marina).  Marina was apparently present for the battle between Agent 3 and DJ Octavio.  Considering the above description for this scroll which states " Anyone lucky enough to catch DJ Octavio's opening set and the Squid Sisters headlining **had their minds blown and their lives changed that night**," I think Marina's life changed after this event, and she decided to join the Inkling society.

Comment: I think this answer is missing a nuance. What the Sunken Scroll suggests is that most of the Octarians are not even aware of DJ Octavio's efforts to invade the surface. They thought his fight with Agent 3 was a concert. They don't see themselves at war with the Inklings, they're simply isolated from them and don't know a lot about the squids -- much like the squids don't know much about the octopuses. As a result of the "concert," Marina did become more interested. in Inklings and went to the surface. But she didn't *defect* from anything.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the Splatfest stage "Shifty Station," which Marina designed, is located below-ground in Octo Canyon. This further suggests that the Inkling and Octoling societies, which were estranged from but not opposed to each other, are getting to know each other better now -- and that Inklings don't have any problems accepting Octolings, and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Well, Marina was brainwashed by Octavio. You can see that clearly at the final Boss where you have to fight Calie and Octavio, but she was brainwashed too, because of the glasses, the same glasses that the Octolings wore.

Answer (score -1):

From my research Octolings are created by cutting off the tentacle from a "host" (DJ Octovio) With no mind of their own, so just being created is kind of brainwashing itself, but in the article it said that the higher IQ Octolings created were put on guard in octo expansion, or ran away. So marina might have been the higher IQ Octoling and ran off to find and join the inkling society.

Comment: Citations to where you found this information would make this answer more helpful.

Answer (score -3):

I think that sense marina is a  dj  and  dj octavio is  one too so i think that he adopted her and  sense  she  was  his  daughter he  let her  take  her  goggles  off and then she  fled to  the  surface for freedom

Answer (score -3):

its in octo expansion now. The answer is the Calamari Inkantation changed her life and her view of the world.

Comment: The glasses have no affect to them, its just so they hide their eyes, i guess.